# Can't convert HttpFileCollectionBase to HttpFileCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a partial view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("add", "home", FormMethod.Post, 
   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){%>
   <input name="IncomingFiles" type="file" />
   <div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextBox("TagsInput") %></div>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p><% } %>
```

And  this in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult add(HttpFileCollection IncomingFiles, string TagsInput)
    {
         return View();
    }
```

It will simply not match up my uploaded file to the HttpFileCollection, they come out as HttpFileCollectionBase.
How can i get the view to pass me a HttpFileCollection?

Do i need any specific BeginForm args?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do something like this instead on your action side.  You don't pass the files as parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult add(string TagsInput) {
  if (Request.Files.Count > 0) {
    // for this example; processing just the first file
         HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
 if (file.ContentLength == 0) {
      // throw an error here if content length is not > 0
      // you'll probably want to do something with file.ContentType and file.FileName
      byte[] fileContent = new byte[file.ContentLength];
      file.InputStream.Read(fileContent, 0, file.ContentLength);
      // fileContent now contains the byte[] of your attachment...
    }  
  }
  return View();
}
```